# how to pass two php variables in to Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have an existing jquery with one PHP variable (`$item_id`) being passed. how can I add one more variable (`$r_id`) along with an existing(`$item_id`) variable?

```
$page_ready_txt[] = ' 
      $(\'.dataTables-region\').DataTable({

      "initComplete": function () {
          var api = this.api();            
          api.$(\'tr\').click( function () {
            document.location = "'. $BASEDIR . '/abc/xyz.php?type=UPD_ITEM&item_id=" + this.id;
          } );
```

Comment: Where is `$item_id` in the code?

Comment: What if you try this ‘ "{$BASEDIR}/abc/xyz.php?type=UPD_ITEM&item_id={$item_id}” ‘